# getting data without <p><bold><em> etc. from database after saving records into database via ckeditor

Tags: html, spring, maven, ckeditor

I am using spring 3.1 mvc and my project is maven project. The data entered in the ckeditor part is saved successfully into the sqldeveloper database. The data is saved in html format like `<p><bold>`, etc. However, when I try to get the data, It is shown as the same recorded in the database such as `<p><bol>example</bold></p>`. How can I get rid of this problem?

news1 can be retrieved correctly. This is controller get method. It is working as I explained. that is, html codes are shown.

```
List <News> newslist= new ArrayList<News>();
newslist.add(news1);
    model.addAttribute("newslist", newslist);
```

In jsp parts,  code is below:

```
<table> 
    <c:forEach items="${newslist}" var="news1" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td>
             <c:out value="${news.field1}" />
         </td>
                        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${news.field2}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Give example bro so we can understand

Comment: @kaan it sounds like your logic for retrieving and displaying the data is incorrect could you post that?

Comment: I wrote the related code. what I need is to get rid of the html tags in the display page but their effects must be available. For example the field1 is bold but <bold> should not be shown in the display page. thanks

Comment: I solved the problem.                                             In controller,  String a = field1.replaceAll("\\s\\s+|\\n|\\r", " "); a= a.replaceAll("\"", "'"); model.addAttribute("a",a);                                        in jsp, <c:out escapeXml="false" value="${a}"></c:out>

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Apache Commons Lang** library for that and method for unescaping HTML.
Download this jar file, add it to your libraries, import it and just call:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(retrivedDataFromDatabase);
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I solved the problem. In controller:
>
> ```
> String a = field1.replaceAll("\\s\\s+|\\n|\\r", " "); 
> a= a.replaceAll("\"", "'");
> model.addAttribute("a",a);
> ```
>
> in jsp:
>
> ```
> <c:out escapeXml="false" value="${a}"></c:out>
> ```